# Android Compose - crossfade with sizechange

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My Composable has the following structure:

```kotlin
var expandedState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Box(modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize()) {
            Crossfade(targetState = expandedState) { expanded ->
                if (expanded) {
                    ExpanedContent()
                } else {
                    CollapsedContent()
                }
            }
}
```

The animation from collapsed to expanded state works as expected: both crossfade and size change animation run simultaneously. When collapsing, though. The crossfade animation runs first, after which the size change animation starts.

How can I animate the state in such a way that the crossfade and size change animations run simultaneously for both directions?

Comment: You need to include the code that does the size change.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the `animate*AsState`, but unfortunately the shorter `animateContentSize` is not usable here. Whenever you move to a targetsize which is smaller, `animateContentSize` does not animate at all. This is because the space in which it can do its animation in, is set before the animation kicks in. So, the space in which you wanted the animation to work in, is already gone. You can see this in the `SizeAnimationModifier` which the `animateContentSize` uses.

Below is an example which should work with `animateDpAsState`, which works by changing a single value:

```
@Composable
fun Foo() {
    var expandedState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val animationDurationMillis = 2000
    val height = animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (expandedState) 500.dp else 30.dp,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = animationDurationMillis,
            easing = LinearEasing
        )
    )

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .height(height.value)
        .clickable { expandedState = !expandedState }) {
        Crossfade(
            targetState = expandedState,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = animationDurationMillis,
                easing = LinearEasing
            )
        ) { expanded ->
            if (expanded) {
                ExpandedContent()
            } else {
                CollapsedContent()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CollapsedContent() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red)
    )
}

@Composable
fun ExpandedContent() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Green)
    )
}
```